# Oracle and Left Outer Join

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, left-join

I am confused about this Hibernate generated Oracle Sql.  There is one user in the database, but they don't have any badges, but I am doing a left outer join on everything.  So the user should come back everytime, regardless of them having a badge.  If I remove these lines, then it pulls back the user.  Isn't left outer join suppose to bring someone back no matter what?

```
AND b4_.ACTIVE=1 
        AND B4_.STATUS='A' 
        AND UB2_.VISIBLE=1 
        and bl3_.ACTIVE=1
```

Hibernate Sql Ran In Sql Developer

```
select
            this_.ID as ID0_11_,
            this_.BIOGRAPHY as BIOGRAPHY0_11_,
            this_.DATECREATED as DATECREA3_0_11_,
            this_.EMAIL as EMAIL0_11_,
            this_.ENABLED as ENABLED0_11_,
            this_.FIRSTNAME as FIRSTNAME0_11_,
            this_.HIDECONNECTORS as HIDECONN7_0_11_,
            this_.HIDEEMAIL as HIDEEMAIL0_11_,
            this_.HIDENAME as HIDENAME0_11_,
            this_.LASTNAME as LASTNAME0_11_,
            this_.PASSWORD as PASSWORD0_11_,
            this_.SALT as SALT0_11_,
            this_.TITLE as TITLE0_11_,
            this_.USERNAME as USERNAME0_11_,
            this_.WARNINGS as WARNINGS0_11_,
            (SELECT
                COUNT(*) 
            FROM
                Followers f 
            WHERE
                f.followerid = this_.Id) as formula0_11_,
            assets6_.USERID as USERID13_,
            asset7_.ID as ASSETID13_,
            asset7_.ID as ID2_0_,
            asset7_.ACTIVE as ACTIVE2_0_,
            asset7_.DATECREATED as DATECREA3_2_0_,
            asset7_.DATEMODIFIED as DATEMODI4_2_0_,
            asset7_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT5_2_0_,
            asset7_.FILENAME as FILENAME2_0_,
            asset7_.FILEPATH as FILEPATH2_0_,
            asset7_.TITLE as TITLE2_0_,
            asset7_.TYPE as TYPE2_0_,
            roles8_.USERID as USERID14_,
            role9_.ID as ROLEID14_,
            role9_.ID as ID1_1_,
            role9_.DISPLAYNAME as DISPLAYN2_1_1_,
            role9_.NAME as NAME1_1_,
            ub2_.USERID as USERID15_,
            ub2_.ID as ID15_,
            ub2_.ID as ID12_2_,
            ub2_.BADGELEVELID as BADGELEV5_12_2_,
            ub2_.DATECREATED as DATECREA2_12_2_,
            ub2_.ISMANUAL as ISMANUAL12_2_,
            ub2_.USERID as USERID12_2_,
            ub2_.VISIBLE as VISIBLE12_2_,
            bl3_.ID as ID9_3_,
            bl3_.ACTIVE as ACTIVE9_3_,
            bl3_.ASSETID as ASSETID9_3_,
            bl3_.BADGEID as BADGEID9_3_,
            bl3_.DATECREATED as DATECREA3_9_3_,
            bl3_.DATEMODIFIED as DATEMODI4_9_3_,
            bl3_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT5_9_3_,
            bl3_.FILTERS as FILTERS9_3_,
            bl3_."ORDER" as ORDER7_9_3_,
            (SELECT
                COUNT(*) 
            FROM
                USERBADGES ub 
            WHERE
                ub.badgeLevelId = bl3_.Id) as formula1_3_,
            (bl3_."ORDER" - 1) as formula2_3_,
            asset12_.ID as ID2_4_,
            asset12_.ACTIVE as ACTIVE2_4_,
            asset12_.DATECREATED as DATECREA3_2_4_,
            asset12_.DATEMODIFIED as DATEMODI4_2_4_,
            asset12_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT5_2_4_,
            asset12_.FILENAME as FILENAME2_4_,
            asset12_.FILEPATH as FILEPATH2_4_,
            asset12_.TITLE as TITLE2_4_,
            asset12_.TYPE as TYPE2_4_,
            b4_.ID as ID10_5_,
            b4_.ACTIVE as ACTIVE10_5_,
            b4_.DATECREATED as DATECREA3_10_5_,
            b4_.DATEMODIFIED as DATEMODI4_10_5_,
            b4_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT5_10_5_,
            b4_.ENDDATE as ENDDATE10_5_,
            b4_.NAME as NAME10_5_,
            b4_.PUBLISHDETAILS as PUBLISHD8_10_5_,
            b4_.STARTDATE as STARTDATE10_5_,
            b4_.STATUS as STATUS10_5_,
            b4_.UPDATEOWNERID as UPDATEO11_10_5_,
            b4_.OWNERID as OWNERID10_5_,
            (SELECT
                COUNT(*) 
            FROM
                BadgeLevels bl 
            WHERE
                bl.badgeId = b4_.Id) as formula3_5_,
            (CASE 
                WHEN (SELECT
                    COUNT(*) 
                FROM
                    BadgeLevels bl 
                WHERE
                    bl.badgeId = b4_.Id)  > 1 THEN 'Ladder' 
                ELSE 'Single' 
            END) as formula4_5_,
            user14_.ID as ID0_6_,
            user14_.BIOGRAPHY as BIOGRAPHY0_6_,
            user14_.DATECREATED as DATECREA3_0_6_,
            user14_.EMAIL as EMAIL0_6_,
            user14_.ENABLED as ENABLED0_6_,
            user14_.FIRSTNAME as FIRSTNAME0_6_,
            user14_.HIDECONNECTORS as HIDECONN7_0_6_,
            user14_.HIDEEMAIL as HIDEEMAIL0_6_,
            user14_.HIDENAME as HIDENAME0_6_,
            user14_.LASTNAME as LASTNAME0_6_,
            user14_.PASSWORD as PASSWORD0_6_,
            user14_.SALT as SALT0_6_,
            user14_.TITLE as TITLE0_6_,
            user14_.USERNAME as USERNAME0_6_,
            user14_.WARNINGS as WARNINGS0_6_,
            (SELECT
                COUNT(*) 
            FROM
                Followers f 
            WHERE
                f.followerid = user14_.Id) as formula0_6_,
            websites15_.USERID as USERID16_,
            website16_.ID as WEBSITEID16_,
            website16_.ID as ID6_7_,
            website16_.ACTIVE as ACTIVE6_7_,
            website16_.DATECREATED as DATECREA3_6_7_,
            website16_.DATEMODIFIED as DATEMODI4_6_7_,
            website16_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT5_6_7_,
            website16_.NAME as NAME6_7_,
            website16_.URL as URL6_7_,
            uc1_.USERID as USERID17_,
            uc1_.ID as ID17_,
            uc1_.ID as ID17_8_,
            uc1_.ACTIVE as ACTIVE17_8_,
            uc1_.CONNECTORID as CONNECTO6_17_8_,
            uc1_.dateCreated as dateCrea3_17_8_,
            uc1_.dateModified as dateModi4_17_8_,
            uc1_.META as META17_8_,
            uc1_.USERID as USERID17_8_,
            connector18_.ID as ID18_9_,
            connector18_.ACTIVE as ACTIVE18_9_,
            connector18_.DATECREATED as DATECREA3_18_9_,
            connector18_.DISPLAYNAME as DISPLAYN4_18_9_,
            connector18_.NAME as NAME18_9_,
            user19_.ID as ID0_10_,
            user19_.BIOGRAPHY as BIOGRAPHY0_10_,
            user19_.DATECREATED as DATECREA3_0_10_,
            user19_.EMAIL as EMAIL0_10_,
            user19_.ENABLED as ENABLED0_10_,
            user19_.FIRSTNAME as FIRSTNAME0_10_,
            user19_.HIDECONNECTORS as HIDECONN7_0_10_,
            user19_.HIDEEMAIL as HIDEEMAIL0_10_,
            user19_.HIDENAME as HIDENAME0_10_,
            user19_.LASTNAME as LASTNAME0_10_,
            user19_.PASSWORD as PASSWORD0_10_,
            user19_.SALT as SALT0_10_,
            user19_.TITLE as TITLE0_10_,
            user19_.USERNAME as USERNAME0_10_,
            user19_.WARNINGS as WARNINGS0_10_,
            (SELECT
                COUNT(*) 
            FROM
                Followers f 
            WHERE
                f.followerid = user19_.Id) as formula0_10_ 
        from
            REWARD.USERS this_ 
        left outer join
            UserAssets assets6_ 
                on this_.ID=assets6_.USERID 
        left outer join
            REWARD.ASSETS asset7_ 
                on assets6_.ASSETID=asset7_.ID 
        left outer join
            UserRoles roles8_ 
                on this_.ID=roles8_.USERID 
        left outer join
            REWARD.ROLES role9_ 
                on roles8_.ROLEID=role9_.ID 
        left outer join
            REWARD.USERBADGES ub2_ 
                on this_.ID=ub2_.USERID 
        left outer join
            REWARD.BADGELEVELS bl3_ 
                on ub2_.BADGELEVELID=bl3_.ID 
        left outer join
            REWARD.ASSETS asset12_ 
                on bl3_.ASSETID=asset12_.ID 
        left outer join
            REWARD.BADGES b4_ 
                on bl3_.BADGEID=b4_.ID 
        left outer join
            REWARD.USERS user14_ 
                on ub2_.USERID=user14_.ID 
        left outer join
            UserWebsites websites15_ 
                on user14_.ID=websites15_.USERID 
        left outer join
            REWARD.WEBSITES website16_ 
                on websites15_.WEBSITEID=website16_.ID 
        left outer join
            REWARD.USERCONNECTORS uc1_ 
                on this_.ID=uc1_.USERID 
        left outer join
            REWARD.CONNECTORS connector18_ 
                on uc1_.CONNECTORID=connector18_.ID 
        left outer join
            REWARD.USERS USER19_ 
                on uc1_.USERID=user19_.ID 
        WHERE
            this_.ID=10100 
            and this_.ENABLED=1 
            AND UC1_.ACTIVE=1 
            AND UB2_.VISIBLE=1
            and bl3_.ACTIVE=1
            AND b4_.ACTIVE=1 
            AND B4_.STATUS='A'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those users do come back but they come back as null for all the columns returned in the tables where the left join didn't find a proper join.

Due to how ANSI nulls work 
b4_.ACTIVE=1 will be invalid for these records because null <> 1

Try restructuring your where block as follows:

```
AND (b4_.ACTIVE=1 or b4_.ACTIVE is null) 
    AND (B4_.STATUS='A' or B4_.STATUS is null) 
    AND (UB2_.VISIBLE=1 or UB2_.VISIBLE is null)
    and (bl3_.ACTIVE=1 or bl3_.ACTIVE is null)
```

Another way to tackle this is add the prerequisites to your left joins.  You can do like I did below and it will exclude the badges where ACTIVE <> 1 excluding bad badges and still return all users.

```
 left outer join
        REWARD.BADGES b4_ 
            on bl3_.BADGEID=b4_.ID 
                AND b4_.ACTIVE=1
```

Comment: Do you know how to do this with hibernate criteria in the second option on the join? or hibernate entities?  I can most certainly do the null portion easily, but that would suck to do that everywhere.

Comment: Hi Mike I hate to say this but you can't do this with hibernate criteria.  You can do this with HQL though using a with statement.  At least as far as I know.