# left outer join in oracle issues

Tags: sql, oracle

In this query below, I need left outer join to work so that resulting dataset contains all the values of a.terr_num that match and unmatch with b.terr_num

somehow this is not working.. please help

```
select   b.sales_regn, b.sales_area,  b.terr_num, a.terr_num,  a.terr_name
from     kp_terr_region b
         left outer join  kap_terr  a on a.terr_num = b.terr_num
where    a.valid_to > sysdate
and      a.ptr_type = 'JPN'
and      a.status != 1
and      a.valid_to > sysdate
and      b.valid_to > sysdate
and      a.slr_num is null;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Join not returning all rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700354) or [Left Outer Join Not Working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467744) or [Oracle and Left Outer Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628961). Remember to do some searching on StackOverflow before posting new questions. As your problem is quite general, you'll find solutions for the issue not necessarily referring to Oracle DB, but nevertheless still relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you are negating your `outer join` with the `where` criteria.  Move that criteria to the `join` instead:

```
select   b.sales_regn, b.sales_area,  b.terr_num, a.terr_num,  a.terr_name
from     kp_terr_region b
     left outer join  kap_terr  a on a.terr_num = b.terr_num
         and a.valid_to > sysdate
         and a.ptr_type = 'JPN'
         and a.status != 1
         and a.slr_num is null
where b.valid_to > sysdate
```